# what will be the best sensor suite for an indoor robot?

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, lidar, rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all ,

I am asking this to get some help from experienced roboticists here. Forgive me if this is not the correct place to ask this question.
We are planning to implement autonomous indoor robot for a large indoor environment for a university project. Is LiDAR  a must for this kind of a robot ? or could we be satisfied with an RGB-D sensor (addition to IMU + odometry)?

Your ideas are really appreciated.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211196/what-will-be-the-best-sensor-suite-for-an-indoor-robot-?/) by [dinesh_sl](https://answers.ros.org/users/18136/dinesh_sl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First you should have a clear definition on your large indoor environment because range sensors like LRF or RGB-D sensor have limitation on distance measurement. For example, Kinect has practical ranging limit around 0.8 – 4 m.

Camera does not have the limitation, but it lacks the absolute info about scale. Also, related tools are less.
LSD-SLAM(Large Scale Direct SLAM) is a good one you might want to take a look. But as far as I know, navigation with monocular is still a problem.

http://vision.in.tum.de/research/lsdslam

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2015-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh_sl](https://answers.ros.org/users/18136/dinesh_sl/) on 2015-06-13**:
Thank you very much. Environment will be populated with still objects like in a library. So range problem will not be a much problem. Because of the cost we are planning to use RGB-D sensor information to laser scan because we are given a 2D map of the environment. Is this a suitable method ? thanks

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2015-06-14**:
Probably works. With pointcloud_to_laserscan (http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan), you can use the navigation package to build your exploring robot system. If your task is patrolling, SMACH can provide a smart solution to handle the whole task.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2015-06-22**:
Or you avoid the costly pointcloud by using depthimage_to_laserscan

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2015-06-22**:
Overall, RGB-D sensor is a good idea since you can use the RGB image or you can transform depth to laser according to your scenario. Though the accuracy might not be as good as LIDAR.